# How to add animation to angularjs uib-alert directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, css-animations, ng-animate

I want to add fade-in animation for new alerts pushed into array and fade-out for dismissed alerts.

Alerts are dismissed automatically after 5 seconds.

I've already included `angular-animate` `ui-bootstrap` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls` libraries.

How can i get these animations working?

See Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ecbCA7h2zVA4XnvUHfFX?p=preview

### HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Alert With Animation</h1>
    <uib-alert 
      ng-repeat="alert in alerts" 
      type="{{alert.type}}" 
      dismiss-on-timeout="5000" 
      close="alerts.splice($index, 1);">{{alert.msg}}
    </uib-alert>
    <input type='text' ng-model='msg' />
    <button ng-click="addAlert(msg,'danger')">Add Alert</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

### SCRIPT

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);

  app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

    $scope.alerts = [];

    $scope.msg = "No Animation!";

    $scope.addAlert = function(msg, type) {
      $scope.alerts.push({
        msg: msg,
        type: type
      });
    };

  });

}());
```

Comment: please refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18844141/2435473) would help you.

Comment: @PankajParkar, well that helped except one little bug. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is based on Pankaj's comment.

Which lead me to this article: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

- added `class='repeat-item'` to `<uib-alert>..</uib-alert>` element.
- added proper stylings for animation effects.

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
  .repeat-item.ng-enter,
  .repeat-item.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
  }

  .repeat-item.ng-enter,
  .repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .repeat-item.ng-leave,
  .repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  </style>
  ```

See working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/CK2lV4mBVGs8q5gyYklE?p=preview

### One little glitch

When you click to add an alert for the very first time, there is no fade-in animation. After that, everything seems OK.

Comment: Thanks! stackoverflow is packed with outdated answers that are not working on angular 1.5.x.
This is working great.