# Can't Use ngClass With Angular UI Bootsrap Alert

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the `uib-alert` directive, but I would like to animate the closing of the alert with Bootstrap's own `fade` class, or other custom animations that I add. I have seen a few other attempts to answer this question, but none were really satisfying.

Previous answers are either outdated ([AngularJS/UI Bootstrap - fading out alert on remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844141/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-fading-out-alert-on-remove)), or rely on CSS classes `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` when angular adds or removes things from the DOM ([How to add animation to angularjs uib-alert directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334601/how-to-add-animation-to-angularjs-uib-alert-directive))

I would prefer an implementation that is

1. More declarative:

   `<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" ng-class="fade: alert.expired" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>`
2. Easier to customize the animation for each alert

   `<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" ng-class="alert.expired ? alert.closeClass : 'fade'" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>`

[Attempting to use ngClass with this directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/GUq2BKRIhYO6Fu7bfEm8?p=preview), results in a console error:

`VM329 angular.js:13424 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 75 of the expression [alert.expired ? alert.closeClass || 'fade' ['alert-' + (type || 'warning'), closeable ? 'alert-dismissible' : null]] starting at [, closeable ? 'alert-dismissible' : null]].`

I also noticed this in the resulting markup, but, oddly,  I don't see this string concatenation or ternary defined anywhere in the source (not in alert template or alert.js):

`ng-class="['alert-' + (type || 'warning'), closeable ? 'alert-dismissible' : null]"`

[There is also a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844141/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-fading-out-alert-on-remove?noredirect=1&lq=1) that attempts to use ngAnimate to solve this problem, but [ngAnimate seems to have no effect on this directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/NABI1yF2bPKvvZcLheZx?p=preview) with the latest version of all packages:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `ng-class`, use `type="{{alert.type}}"`. This will solve the problem   [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/29Bzo4kb9NOMkKnDBpSl?p=preview)

```
<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" dismiss-on-timeout= 20>{{alert.msg}}</div>
```